# when should the child object be declared as a member variable of its parent class in qt?

Tags: c++, qt

```
//disconnect.h
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

class Disconnect : public QWidget {

  Q_OBJECT  

  public:
    Disconnect(QWidget *parent = 0);

  private slots:
    void onClick();
    void onCheck(int);

  private:
    QPushButton *clickBtn;
};
```

---

```
//disconnect.cpp
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include "disconnect.h"

Disconnect::Disconnect(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent) {

  QHBoxLayout *hbox = new QHBoxLayout(this);
  hbox->setSpacing(5);        

  clickBtn = new QPushButton("Click", this);
  hbox->addWidget(clickBtn, 0, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);

  QCheckBox *cb = new QCheckBox("Connect", this);
  cb->setCheckState(Qt::Checked);
  hbox->addWidget(cb, 0, Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);

  connect(clickBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Disconnect::onClick);
  connect(cb, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &Disconnect::onCheck);  
}

void Disconnect::onClick() {

  QTextStream out(stdout);
  out << "Button clicked" << endl;
}

void Disconnect::onCheck(int state) {

  if (state == Qt::Checked) {
    connect(clickBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &Disconnect::onClick);
  } else {
    disconnect(clickBtn, &QPushButton::clicked, this, 
        &Disconnect::onClick);
  }
}
```

---

```
//main.cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include "disconnect.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  QApplication app(argc, argv);  

  Disconnect window;

  window.resize(250, 150);
  window.setWindowTitle("Disconnect");
  window.show();

  return app.exec();
}
```

In the above code，A Disconnect object has two child object——a QPushButton and a  QcheckBox, but class Disconnect only have a QPushButton pointer, not a QcheckBox pointer. Can anyone tell me when should the child object be declared as a member variable of its parent class in qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me when should the child object be declared as a
>   member variable of its parent class in qt?

If you think you will need to call methods on (or otherwise access) the child object from other methods of parent class (as your example code does with `clickBtn`, referencing it from the `onCheck` method), then you'll want to create a member variable that is a pointer to that child object, to allow you to do so.

If, on the other hand, you will not need to access the child object outside of the method where it was created, then you can keep your parent class's definition shorter and simpler by declaring the pointer-to-the-child-object as a local variable inside the creating method only.